# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova Hosted web app home screen become a blank screen after associated with the existing windows store app?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-cordova

I have created, Hosted web app using Apache Cordova on Visual Studio 2015. After creation of a web app (without associated with existing windows store app) debug it. Its display the Splash Screen and next its displaying Home screen of web app. Everything's working fine for me. But, once I have an associate web App with existing windows store App. Again, I have tried to debug the Web App. Its showing only Splash Screen of app and place of home screen only showing a blank screen.

Comment: What errors did you get? And on which Platform are you running the App?(Windows, Android or IOS)

Comment: I am trying to create app for Windows 10 Store and app not throwing any Erorr but screen is white. I think page not redirect to URL.

Comment: One more thing when I try to create package VS 2015 throwing error.So, I unable to create a package for windows 10.
1. The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AppxManifestXml".[E:\edtestapp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]

2. Error : C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe : Command failed with exit code 1

Can you please help me to find out the solution of this issue.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2015 are you using? If you are not on the latest update (Update 3), I encourage you to update. That will likely fix the packaging error at least.

Comment: Sry for late response, have you tried it with release mode?

Comment: I have found out the issue. If I select target version win 8. Hosted App unable to redirect to a URL. Because of this my app become white screen. Finally I have changed the target version to win 10. Now, everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution!

The error only occur, when i install cordova and plugins over CLI, but when
i start a cordova project over visual studio 2015 and use the integrated plugin manager -> so it works without any error.

Kevin